# Are java annotations with typed class parameter possible?

Tags: java, annotations

Let's supposed i have this interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
   void doStuff();
}
```

With a concrete implementation:

```
public class HardCoreConcrete implements MyInterface {
   void doStuff() {
      // i really do stuff, honest
   }
}
```

And suppose i have this annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   Class<MyInterface> clazz;
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(clazz = HardCoreConcrete.class)
public class SomeOtherClass {
...
}
```

Why does this not work? My compiler complains that for clazz it expected type MyInterface! But HardCoreConcrete implements MyInterface.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this not allowed? Am i out of luck?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940610/how-do-you-ensure-a-class-annotation-parameter-extends-an-interface-at-compile-t.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {    
   Class<? extends MyInterface> clazz;
}
```

Comment: Just to explain: `Class<MyInterface>` can hold **only** the `Class` object describing `MyInterface`. It can hold nothing else (and thus is pretty useless in an annotation).