# How do you ensure a class annotation parameter extends an interface at compile time?

Tags: java, annotations

I have an annotation I'm attempting to define that takes a Class parameter. I would like to ensure that the Class provided extends a specific interface. So I came up with...

```
public @interface Tag {
    Class<? extends ITagStyle> style() default NoStyle.class
}
public class NoStyle implements ITagStyle {
    ...
}
```

However I get a compile error of "incompatible types".

I'm assuming this is because `NoStyle.class` is returning `Class` instead of `Class<NoStyle>`. In the JLS for Java SE 5 & 7 (couldn't find 6, I'm using 6) it specifically says that "void.class" would return "Class". SEE JLS Class literals: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.8.2

Is there anyway to do this at compile time? If not I'm guessing the workround is to check the value of style at runtime to ensure it extends ITagStyle :'(

**RESOLUTION:** JDeveloper has a bug in their "in process" compiler. Checking "out of process" or using JDK7u3 corrects the compile error.

Comment: Works for me. What's the full error-message?

Comment: Error:  incompatible types. Also to be more specific, I'm using jdk1.6.0_26... maybe a bug?

Comment: I am using 1.6.0_29. Are you using Eclipse? Is your Java Compiler Compliance level also set to 1.6?

Comment: I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.2.0.0, the current compiler is set to javac.

Comment: Try compiling it using a command line and see if the same error occurs.

Comment: I'm installing java 7u3 at the moment. I'll report back if its working

Comment: WOW, adarshr you were right on. I checked "out of process" compiler and it compiles just fine.

Comment: JDeveloper must have a bug in there "in process" javac compiler. I also installed Java 7u3 and then JDeveloper automatically does out of process and it compiles fine also. So looks like my code is correct just a problem with compiler.

Comment: Glad we sorted it out :)

Comment: adarshr, if you post an answer I can accept since you pin pointed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This works, so either you are missing something obvious or your error is not related to what you are showing us:

```
public class Test {

    public interface ITagStyle {
    }

    public @interface Tag {
        Class<? extends ITagStyle> style() default NoStyle.class;
    }

    public class NoStyle implements ITagStyle {
    }

    public class SomeStyle implements ITagStyle {

    }

    @Tag(style = SomeStyle.class)
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

This has been tested on JDK 1.6.0_26